# Tooltip Stays open after you click away

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tooltip, material-ui

I'm using [material UI Tooltip](https://material-ui.com/components/tooltips/), and on an iphone the tooltip doesn't go away after one clicks on it. It goes away on android and on desktop, but on the iPhone it stays open after you click on it.

```
            <Tooltip
                disableFocusListener
                disableTouchListener
                interactive
                title={
                    <p className='tooltip-text'>
                        This is the most awesome message!
                    </p>
                }
            >
                <MUIbutton>My Tooltip</MUIbutton>
            </Tooltip
```

I already trie removing `disableFocusListener`, `disableTouchListener`, and `interactive`, but it still stays opened. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: which version of MUI are you using ?

Comment: @SafiNettah The latest one.

Comment: And if you add a `leaveDelay` like https://material-ui.com/components/tooltips/#showing-and-hiding